# VectorDrawable as Image source in NativeScript

Tags: android, nativescript, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to use android's `VectorDrawable` as `Image` source in NativeScript. Using layout inspector I can see that there is something but no image is displayed. Also there is no error about missing image file, no errors at all.

I couldn't find out whether it's possible or not.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I somehow figured it out:

```
let context = application.android.context;
// vector is VectorDrawable name
        let logo = context.getResources()
            .getIdentifier(this.vector, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        this.el.nativeElement.android.setBackgroundResource(logo);

        // Access CSS color to change fill color
        let backgroundColor: string = (this.el.nativeElement.backgroundColor)
            ? this.el.nativeElement.backgroundColor.toString()
            : SrcDirective.DEFAULT_COLOR;

        let newBackgroundColor: Color = new Color(backgroundColor);

        this.el.nativeElement.android.getBackground().setTint(newBackgroundColor.android);
```